# Bash to start and kill process on Ubuntu in a given period

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have this situation: I have a script in php running on ubuntu terminal (xfce4-terminal) as a console/process (in php there is a loop with some process).
The problem is: every two days this process is killed due to memory overuse.
What I need is: A bash script that can start the process and every 48hrs it kills this process and start it again.

Comment: If your process runs for 48hrs, would you like to explain what process takes this long and needs restarting periodically? That sounds like an unusual process

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't configured this as a systemd service? If it's running as a service, it'll be automatically started on boot, restarted whenever it dies, and you can set up a timer to trigger an explicit restart when desired *or* just configure a maximum on how much memory it's allowed to use, and let it die and get restarted when it exceeds that maximum.

Comment: ...which is to say, writing a bash script is the wrong way to address this problem in the first place.

Comment: I agree with @RiggsFolly on this one. Sounds like "I have a car where the alternator goes out each week. I need to build a machine that changes the alternator of my car every Saturday to resolve the issue". Is the memory leak fixable? Is there another way to do whatever this php script is doing using cron and shell or something...?

Comment: I think this is a FIX THE PROBLEM situation rather than FIX THE SYMPTOM

Comment: @RiggsFolly. thanks for your answer. My process is a curl and get_file_contents tha get some objects (json) and save in mywql in 10 in 10 seconds. It is a loop, shouldn't never stopped, but it is killed in 48hrs. I tryed clean the memory periodically, but didin't work.

Comment: I sounds like this could be changed to be started once an hour or day using cron. Then amend the script to terminate itself after an hour or day so you dont have 2 running. Or maybe get the script to run for a day, then terminate and reschedule itself as part of the termination process. To be done at the quietest part of the day, whenever that may be

Answer (score 0):

The optimal solution is fixing the memory leak, trace the leaking function and post a new question with the relevant code if you need help.

Now for this specific case you can use something like this:

```
while true
do 
  timeout 12h php myfile.php
done
```

This is a infinite loop that starts your command and kills it afer 12 hours. (or any other duration you want: 30m, 1d, etc)

A more stable solution is creating a systemd service or deploying your script using some process manager like Supervisor or Monit.

Supervisor has a config parameter "autorestart", if you specify true it restarts your script every time it crashes, and this is a stable production ready solution.

A sample supervisor config from [this post](https://flotz-chronicles.com/script/php/2015/08/18/running-php-script-forever-with-supervisor.html)

```
[program:are_we_there_yet]
command=php /var/www/areWeThereYet.php
numprocs=1
directory=/tmp
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=5
startretries=10
redirect_stderr=false
```